# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor recursive function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Okay, so I want to display a list containing lists of lists of lists...

I have no way of knowing how many levels there are to display, so I figured this is where I break out the old recursive routine.

I'm having trouble with exactly how to go about this though.

This is what I have so far (in view - simplified):

```
@foreach(MyObject item in @Model.ListOfObjects){ 
    <div> @item.Title </div>
    //Call recursive function?
}
```

Now each of these objects also have a List<MyObject>. I want to display each level below this div, with a tab indent per level for instance.

I was thinking a Razor function would be the thing to do here, but I need some help in forming it. Here's my thinking:

```
@functions{
    public static void ShowSubItems(MyObject _object){
         if(_object.ListOfObjects.Count>0){
             foreach(MyObject subItem in _object.listOfObjects){

                 // Show subItem in HTML
                 ShowSubItems(subItem);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

But as you can see, I plainly need some help :)

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The Razor view engine allows to write inline recursive helpers with the `@helper` keyword.

```
@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            <li>
                @foo.Title
                @if (foo.Children.Any())
                {
                    @ShowTree(foo.Children)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: one thing is remaining that it must call on view by **@ShowTree(Foos)**

Comment: This works really well. Also may make sense to mention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943245/access-global-page-variable-in-helper for referencing local variables on the cshtml page.

Comment: how can be implemented this code in asp.net core 2? 
in asp.net core 2, there is no @helper

Comment: @Jahan Looks like `@helper`s are gone in ASP.NET Core. Inline functions are one potential alternative: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/715#issuecomment-272890766 but look much less readable!

Comment: @PaoloMoretti When I define it as recursive Func, how can I do it?
I want to create a nested comments with recursive Func.
This error shows in VS2018 IDE:
"Use of unassigned local variable 'FunctionName' local variable 'FunctionName' might not be initialized before accessing"

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Please visit this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48211043/1817640

Answer (score 13):

I think it is best to create an HTML helper for this. Something like this:

```
public static string ShowSubItems(this HtmlHelper helper, MyObject _object)
{
     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
     if(_object.ListOfObjects.Count > 0)
     {
         output.Append("<ul>");

         foreach(MyObject subItem in _object.listOfObjects)
         {
             output.Append("<li>");
             output.Append(_object.Title);
             output.Append(html.ShowSubItems(subItem.listOfObjects);
             output.Append("</li>")
         }
         output.Append("</ul>");
     }
     return output.ToString();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
@foreach(MyObject item in @Model.ListOfObjects){
    <div> @item.Title </div>
    @html.ShowSubItems(item)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In .Net core Instead of helper tag we have to use @functions. This below code might useful to some people. Here "IssuerData" is my custom object

```
@{
      ShowTreeData(Model.HierarchyList);
}

    @functions{

  public static void ShowTreeData(IList<IssuerData> issuers)
      {
       <ul>
      @foreach (var i in issuers)
           {
           <li>
            @i.IssuerName
             @if (i.Children.Any())
               {
                 ShowTreeData(i.Children);
               }
            </li>
          }
       </ul>
       }
   }
```