# How to write recursive view in MVC cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, recursion, view, razor

Is it possible to write a cascading, recursive "tree view" (e.g. a li in ul, ul in li, etc) in pure cshtml, **without** moving the whole thing to a partial view and calling `@Html.Partial("itself",Model.Children)` from the partial view?

Something like an inline recursive function, or section...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 Razor recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422895/mvc3-razor-recursive-function)