# Access global page variable in helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}

@helper Text() {
    <input type="text" name="Ans[@i].Text" />
}
```

`i` is not accessible in helper. How to access it?

Comment: Can the declaration not be moved closer to usage? I think your issue here is that the variable is out of scope.

Comment: It is possible to use variable outside of helper but impossible in it. I can't move it inside. The only solution is to pass as parameter but it's not very nice.

Comment: I would disagree with it being "very nice", it could be your only option. Does what you are doing have to be in a helper?

Comment: Can you stick it in the ViewBag or ViewData collections?

Comment: Pass `i` to the helper. Or perhaps try to use `<input type="text" name="Ans[@(i)].Text" />`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can simply add it as member to you page by using **@functions** declaration:

```
@functions
{
    private int i;
}
```

Comment: WOW... this one is amazing! Thanks for sharing... :) Saved me. If I pass an `int` parameter to the helper and increment it there then try to read it outside the helper; it has the initial value since `int` is a value type (a copy is passed as parameter and not the original int ref). In Razor's helper it's also not possible to use `ref int` because helpers are intrinsically lambda expressions: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-7-helpers.html/

Comment: @LenielMacaferi and thank YOU for mentioning that about `ref` in your comment... I suspected that was the case, but you saved me a bunch more digging.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. It's much more in line with what the question was asking, and it's exactly what I need. I need to be able to change the value in my helper. It's such a silly thing I need, doesn't make sense to make a view model or do anything complicated. Great answer!

Comment: Note that you can't access the Model from there

Answer (score 11):

You could pass it as parameter to the helper:

```
@helper Text(int i) {
    <input type="text" name="Ans[@i].Text" />
}
```

and then:

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}
@SomeHelper.Text(i)
```

or you could simply use editor templates which will take care of everything and get rid of those helpers. For example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Ans)
```

Comment: Hello @Darin, I want to get the changed value back from my '@helper' I can't use ref and out there, how it can be solved.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by changing base class for your view. This scenario applies to situation where helper is declared in view.

Create a base class that inherits from [WebViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg402107%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and introduce shared field or property:

```
public class MyBasePage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public int i;

    public override void Execute()
    { }
}
```

Using `@inherits` directive change base class. And now field/property is acessible both from "page context" and helper:

```
@inherits NamespaceOfYourBaseClass.MyBasePage<YourModel>
@{
    i = 0;
}

@helper Text() {
    <input type="text" name="Ans[@i].Text" />
}
```

---

If you want to have a thing that is close to term "page property/field" but dont want to create a base class or helpers are stored within `App_Code` folder then you can try [WebPageBase.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.page%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) property.

> **MSDN**: Provides property-like access to page data that is shared between
>   pages, layout pages, and partial pages.

The code in this case would be:

```
@{
    Page.i = 0;
}

@helper Text() {
    <input type="text" name="Ans[@Page.i].Text" />
}
```

The drawback is that `Page` property is of type `dynamic` and thus does not support intellisense. As an alternative to `Page` there is another property - [WebPageBase.PageData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.pagedata%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

> **MSDN**: Provides array-like access to page data that is shared between pages,
>   layout pages, and partial pages.

In this case a class-container of strings/ints keys for "page variables" could be created. And the code would be like:

```
// class visible to views and helpers
class MyViewFields {
  public const string i = "MyViewFields.i"; // or maybe generate guid for key so there would be not doubts about its uniqueness.. but how would you debug this? :)
}

// in MyView.cshtml
@{
    PageData[MyViewFields.i] = 0
}

@helper Text() {
    <input type="text" name="Ans[@PageData[MyViewFields.i]].Text" />
}
```

This at least provides constraints for shared page data but still no control over value type.