# ASP.NET MVC : Generating multi level menu using recursive helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, recursion, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I am using this code for generating menu, this menu populates items from database (Category Table) using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422895/mvc3-razor-recursive-function)

**Partial View :**

```
@using SarbarzDarb.Helper
@model IEnumerable<SarbarzDarb.Models.Entities.Category>

@ShowTree(Model)

@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<SarbarzDarb.Models.Entities.Category> categories)
{
        foreach (var item in categories)
        {
            <li class="@(item.ParentId == null && item.Children.Any() ? "dropdown-submenu" : "")">

                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, actionName: "Category", controllerName: "Product", routeValues: new { Id = item.Id, productName = item.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes: null)

                @if (item.Children.Any())
                {
                    ShowTree(item.Children);
                }

            </li>

        }
}
```

also I'm passing model from controller to above partial view this way :

```
public IList<Category> GetAll()
{

        return _category.Where(category => category.ParentId == null)
                        .Include(category => category.Children).ToList();
}
public ActionResult Categories()
{
            var query = GetAll();
            return PartialView("_Categories",query);
}
```

my Category Model:

```
public class Category
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

 }
```

**Updated :**
using recursive helpers are good idea but it doesn't generate sub-menu for me. what's my problem?
**Any Idea?**

**Thanks in your advise**

Comment: This question seems to have the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422895/mvc3-razor-recursive-function

Comment: @hwiechers yes I know I've updated my answer, but still have problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

finally I solved my problem by adding `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` :

```
@using SarbarzDarb.Helper
@model IEnumerable<SarbarzDarb.Models.Entities.Category>
@ShowTree(Model)

@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<SarbarzDarb.Models.Entities.Category> categories)
{
    foreach (var item in categories)
    {
    <li class="@(item.Children.Any() ? "dropdown-submenu" : "")">

        @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, actionName: "Category", controllerName: "Product", 
        routeValues: new { Id = item.Id, productName = item.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes: null)
        @if (item.Children.Any())
        {
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @ShowTree(item.Children)
            </ul>
                }
    </li>

        }
}
```