# ASP.Net MVC: How to show nested parent-child relation using recursive technique

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am just trying to display nth relation using `ul` and `li` in razor using recursive function call. Suppose I have db table where I store parent child relation like below one.

### table structure

```
+----+----------+----------+
| ID | Name     | ParentID |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | Parent 1 | 0        |
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  | child 1  | 1        |
+----+----------+----------+
| 3  | child 2  | 1        |
+----+----------+----------+
| 4  | child 3  | 1        |
+----+----------+----------+
| 5  | Parent   | 0        |
+----+----------+----------+
| 6  | child 4  | 4        |
+----+----------+----------+
```

So i like to show the nested data this way in razor view

```
Parent 1
    child 1
    child 2
    child 3
        child 4
Parent
```

So this code i tried but could not achieve the goal.

**c# POCO classes**

```
public class MenuItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
}

public class MenuDTO 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Action code**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<MenuItem> allMenu = new List<MenuItem>
        {
            new MenuItem {Id=1,Name="Parent 1", ParentId=0},
            new MenuItem {Id=2,Name="child 1", ParentId=1},
            new MenuItem {Id=3,Name="child 2", ParentId=1},
            new MenuItem {Id=4,Name="child 3", ParentId=1},
            new MenuItem {Id=5,Name="Parent 2", ParentId=0},
            new MenuItem {Id=6,Name="child 4", ParentId=4}
        };


        List<MenuDTO> mi = allMenu
        .Select(e => new
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            Name = e.Name,
            ParentId = e.ParentId,
            Children = allMenu.Where(x => x.ParentId == e.Id).ToList()
        }).ToList()
        .Select(p => new MenuDTO
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            ParentId = p.ParentId,
            Children = p.Children
            //Children = p.Children.Cast<MenuDTO>()
        }).ToList();

        ViewBag.menusList = mi;

        return View();
    }
```

**Razor code**

```
@{
    var menuList = ViewBag.menusList as List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuDTO>;
    ShowTree(menuList);
}


@helper ShowTree(List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuDTO> menusList)
{
    if (menusList != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in menusList)
        {
            <li>
                <span>@item.Name</span>
                @if (item.Children.Any())
                {
                    <ul>
                        @ShowTree(item.Children)
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        }
    }
}
```

in my case i am query List allMenu to get data instead from db table. when i am running my code then i am getting below error

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'ASP._Page_Views_Menu_Index_cshtml.ShowTree(System.Collections.Generic.List)'
>   has some invalid arguments

tell me what is wrong in my code. please help me to fix and acquire my goal. thanks

### EDIT

Full working code as following

```
@helper ShowTree(List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuItem> menusList)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in menusList)
        {
            <li>
                <span>@item.Name</span>
                @if (item.Children!=null && item.Children.Any())
                {
                    @ShowTree(item.Children)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@{
    var menuList = ViewBag.menusList as List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuItem>;
    @ShowTree(menuList);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{

    List<MenuItem> allMenu = new List<MenuItem>
    {
        new MenuItem {Id=1,Name="Parent 1", ParentId=0},
        new MenuItem {Id=2,Name="child 1", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=3,Name="child 2", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=4,Name="child 3", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=5,Name="Parent 2", ParentId=0},
        new MenuItem {Id=6,Name="child 4", ParentId=4}
    };

    List<MenuItem> mi = allMenu
    .Where(e => e.ParentId == 0) /* grab only the root parent nodes */
    .Select(e => new MenuItem
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Name = e.Name,
        ParentId = e.ParentId,
        Children = allMenu.Where(x => x.ParentId == e.Id)  /* grab second level children */
            .Select(e2 => new MenuItem
            {
                Id = e2.Id,
                Name = e2.Name,
                ParentId = e2.ParentId,
                Children = allMenu.Where(x2 => x2.ParentId == e2.Id).ToList() /* grab third level children */
            }).ToList()
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.menusList = mi;

    return View();
}

public class MenuItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ShowTree is expecting a list but you are sending the item  @ShowTree(item.Children) . If you replace @ShowTree(item.Children) with @ShowTree(item) it will pass the list to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not able to find a function ShowTree taking a parameter of type `ICollection<MenuItem>` when it executes the line

```
@ShowTree(item.Children)
```

because item.Children is of type `ICollection<MenuItem>`.  The function ShowTree in your code takes a parameter of a different type, `List<MenuDTO>`, which is not the same as `ICollection<MenuItem>`.  As a result, the runtime reports the CS1502 error you see.

After realizing that you were looking for a recursive solution, I have modified the code to do just that.

**Action Code**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    List<MenuItem> allMenu = new List<MenuItem>
    {
        new MenuItem {Id=1,Name="Parent 1", ParentId=0},
        new MenuItem {Id=2,Name="child 1", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=3,Name="child 2", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=4,Name="child 3", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=5,Name="Parent 2", ParentId=0},
        new MenuItem {Id=6,Name="child 4", ParentId=4}
    };

    List<MenuItem> mi = allMenu
    .Where(e => e.ParentId == 0) /* grab only the root parent nodes */
    .Select(e => new MenuItem
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Name = e.Name,
        ParentId = e.ParentId,
        Children = GetChildren(allMenu, e.Id) /* Recursively grab the children */
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.menusList = mi;

    return View();
}

/// <summary>
/// Recursively grabs the children from the list of items for the provided parentId
/// </summary>
/// <param name="items">List of all items</param>
/// <param name="parentId">Id of parent item</param>
/// <returns>List of children of parentId</returns>
private static List<MenuItem> GetChildren(List<MenuItem> items, int parentId)
{
    return items
        .Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId)
        .Select(e => new MenuItem
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            Name = e.Name,
            ParentId = e.ParentId,
            Children = GetChildren(items, e.Id)
        }).ToList();
}
```

**Razor Code**

```
@{
    var menuList = ViewBag.menusList as List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuItem>;
    @ShowTree(menuList);
}

@helper ShowTree(List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuItem> menusList)
{
    if (menusList != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in menusList)
        {
            <li>
                <span>@item.Name</span>
                @if (item.Children.Any())
                {
                    <ul>
                        @ShowTree(item.Children)
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is one error in your code that is  ShowTree(menuList); it should be @ ShowTree(menuList); then ShowTree will be called and write data in page. anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Good catch!  Sorry, I didn't get a chance to test the code.  **I just wanted you to be aware that the algorithm may have left out _child 4_**.  If you know that there will be exactly three levels of menu items, then you can add another level of `Where(...).Select {...}.ToList()` clauses for the `Children` property of the current `Select` clause to cover the third menu level (where _child 4_ sits).

Comment: please look into the above code tell me what to change their as a result nested child should be shown. when i run my program then child 4 name is not showing which is child of child 3. what is the problem in code and tell me what to fix if you know. thanks

Comment: I went ahead and modified the query in your "Full working code".  I'm new to contributing, so I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I finally realized that I was missing the recursive query part that you wanted, and I have added that to my solution.  Please test and update your "Full working code" with the new changes.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed and did the job this way

the problem was in logic of razor code and also i comment this line `//.Where(e => e.ParentId == 0)` here i am adding working code.

**working code sample**

```
@helper  ShowTree(List<NestedChild.Controllers.MenuItem> menu, int? parentid = 0, int level = 0)
{
    var items = menu.Where(m => m.ParentId == parentid);

    if (items.Any())
    {
        if (items.First().ParentId > 0)
        {
            level++;
        }

        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in items)
            {
            <li>
                @item.Name
            </li>
                @ShowTree(menu, item.Id, level);
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
@{
    var menuList = ViewBag.menusList as List<NestedChild.Controllers.MenuItem>;
    @ShowTree(menuList);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MenuItem> allMenu = new List<MenuItem>
    {
        new MenuItem {Id=1,Name="Parent 1", ParentId=0},
        new MenuItem {Id=2,Name="child 1", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=3,Name="child 2", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=4,Name="child 3", ParentId=1},
        new MenuItem {Id=5,Name="Parent 2", ParentId=0},
        new MenuItem {Id=6,Name="child 4", ParentId=4}
    };

    List<MenuItem> mi = allMenu
    //.Where(e => e.ParentId == 0) /* grab only the root parent nodes */
    .Select(e => new MenuItem
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Name = e.Name,
        ParentId = e.ParentId,
        //Children = allMenu.Where(x => x.ParentId == e.Id).ToList()
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.menusList = mi;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: That looks great!  I like your solution better.  If the list came from the database, my code would be slower as it makes more round trips to the database for each set of children.  Your code would make one query with the trade-off of hierarchy traversal after getting the results, which should be faster.

Comment: FYI, you no longer need the `Children = allMenu.Where(x => x.ParentId == e.Id).ToList()` line or the `Children` property at all.  It will only slow your code.

Comment: yes you are right. i will comment those line. thanks for your help and support.