# How to implement a simple TreeView using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, treeview, visual-studio-2019

I am a newbie on web development, and I want to build a very simple website using VS2019, based on MVC structure. I need to create a treeview in a webpage, with selectable node, as simple as possible.

I have no problem on loading data, populate to any structure / class. However, I have no idea on how to show a treeview in a webpage.

I have been searching for four hours. I see a lot of js tree plug-ins, a lot of TreeView controller in NuGet. I just want a simple tree, better from Microsoft not any other 3rd party. I see a TreeView WebControl but it seems for Web Form application (.aspx).

Please don't tell me to search the internet, as I really tried, very hard.
Big thanks!

If it is nothing out-of-box from Microsoft to be used in cshtml, please confirm this and I will stop searching, and if possible, please recommend a most easy-learn and use way of using TreeView.

jstree / Telerik / ???

[image]

Comment: For cshtml you need recursion function for your nested data list. For javascript (jstree) you need return json with nested json objects. But please clarify your question because I don't belive you can't find tree sample on the internet.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213000/asp-net-mvc-generating-multi-level-menu-using-recursive-helpers

Comment: @daremachine I can find a lot, but either use javascript, jquery, or bunch of 3rd party plugins. I wonder is there anything ready for use from Microsoft, and better not using anything other than html. My question could be stupid as I really weak on web development.

Comment: Microsoft make tools not components. If you want completed components you probably want 3rd party such as Telerik or Syncfusion. Or you can be first who make opensource tree component in nuget or you take others. You have many options.

Comment: @ darrmachine thanks a lot, i know there was a treeview web control in the past, and i guess it was old tech because it runs on the server side? Now things change. Raw html does not support treeview, right? So it has to be done through something like js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tony, I have been searching for the same thing also.  You are right, there is a TreeView for ASP.NET Core, but it's for Windows Forms and not web pages:

[Microsoft Docs TreeView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview?view=netcore-3.1)

I have also looked at Telerik and Syncfusion, but am trying to avoid paying for a solution.

First, for the data structure, I did find a NuGet package called TreeCollections written by David West here:

https://github.com/davidwest/TreeCollections

I have implemented that and can successfully build one or multiple hierarchical trees from my data.  You might want to look at that for your tree data structure.

Now to display the data on a web page, I don't think Microsoft has any tools to help us.  I have searched like you have.  You mention [JsTree](https://www.jstree.com), and I think that is a viable option, but it's not html-only as you specified.  I think we will have to use at least some javascript.

There are two good lazy-load implementations of JSTree on SO here:  [Lazy-loading TreeView with JsTree in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290570/lazy-loading-treeview-with-jstree-in-asp-net-mvc)

Depending on the size and depth of your tree, if you can pull your data dynamically as the user navigates the tree, this might be the best solution.  If you want to pre-load your data into a tree structure first, like I am doing with TreeCollections, then perhaps populating a  structure will work, but it will still need help with javascript if you want to interactively show/hide branches on the tree.

---

Update:  I was able to load and display a hierarchical tree on my web page with very little code, using [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com).  I found I didn't need TreeCollections at all.  First, the model that holds each node's data:

```
public class JsTreeModel
 {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public bool opened { get; set; }
    public bool disabled { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public string li_attr { get; set; }
    public string a_attr { get; set; }
 }
```

Here's my code that loads the data into a List.  I am working in ASP.Net Core 3.1, so I use System.Text.Json to serialize the data.  First retrieve your data from the db into a List<> of items, no sorting is required. Then:

```
  using System.Text.Json;
  [...]
  IList<JsTreeModel> nodes = new List<JsTreeModel>();

  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    nodes.Add(new JsTreeModel
    {
      id = item.Id.ToString(),
      parent = item.ParentId == null ? "#" : item.ParentId.ToString(),
      text = item.Name
    });
  }

  //Serialize to JSON string.
  ViewBag.Json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(nodes);

  return View();
```

Then in your view, you simply need one div that holds the tree:

```
<div id="jstree"></div>
```

and this javascript that will populate it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#jstree').jstree({ 
    "core" : {
       "data" : @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Json)
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

jsTree will go through the Json data and create a ul structure from it and put that into the div.  Very easy!

Comment: given solution display flat treeview, not hierarchical. Any way to show hierarchical treeview

Comment: The hierarchy of the tree is determined by the relationships in your List<JsTreeModel>(). Items in the list with a ParentId will fall under that ID node in the tree, thus creating a hierarchical tree.

Comment: it worked thanks