# Creating recursive method helper with Func<>

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, html-helper, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two method helper with theses signatures:

> @helper CreateNavigation(int parentId, int depthNavigation)
>
> @helper Navigation(int parentId, int depthNavigation)

I have tried to convert it to a proper method for using in `ASP.NET Core 2`.

But I got an error in `VS2017 IDE` that is:

> 1- Use of unassigned local variable 'Navigation'
>   2- local variable
>   'Navigation' might not be initialized before accessing

How can I fix it?

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
@model List<Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Models.Comment>

@{
    Func<int, int, int, HelperResult> CreateNavigation
        = (parentId, depthNavigation) => new Func<object, HelperResult>(
    @<text>@{
                Comment parent = Model.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == parentId);
                depthNavigation = 6;
        @Navigation(parentId, depthNavigation)
    }</text>)(null);
}
@{

    Func<int, int, HelperResult> Navigation
        = (parentId, depthNavigation) => new Func<object, HelperResult>(
    @<text>@{
                var parent = Model.Children(parentId);
                if (//condition)
                {
                    if (//condition)
                    {
                        foreach (var comment in Model)
                        {
                            if (//condition)
                            {
                                <li><p>@comment.Description</p></li>
                                @Navigation(comment.Id, depthNavigation)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    }</text>)(null);
}
```

Comment: Declare your variables **BEFORE** declaring the methods then and initlize then with `null`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I was able to solve it by declaring the delegate first and setting it to null, then adding the implementation like this:

```
@{Func<IEnumerable<Foo>, IHtmlContent> DisplayTree = null;}
@{DisplayTree = @<text>@{
  var foos = item;
  <ul>
  @foreach (var foo in foos)
  {
  <li>
    @foo.Title
    @if (foo.Children.Any())
    {
      @DisplayTree(foo.Children)
    }
  </li>
  }
  </ul>
}</text>;}


@DisplayTree(new List<Foo>{...})
```