# Optimized way to display child and parent in HTML C#

Tags: c#, html, recursion, optimization

I managed to display a folder tree with Parent/Child relationships between them. But the way I did it is really not optimized and very ugly.

[My tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNKZI.png)

I have an @model which contains items with the following attributes:

- *Id* (item id)
- *Libelle* (item name)
- *Pere* (Id of the parent of the item)
- *Niveau* (Place of the item in the hierarchy of the tree)

Here is the code that works:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <div class="bloc-mise-en-page">
        <div id="arbo-dossier-2">
                    @if (item.Niveau == 1)
                    {
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" id=@item.Libelle><label for=@item.Libelle>@item.Libelle</label>
                                @foreach (var item1 in Model)
                                {
                                @if ((item1.Niveau == 2) && (item1.Pere == item.Id)) 
                                {
                                  <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id=@item1.Libelle><label for=@item1.Libelle>@item1.Libelle</label>
                                        @foreach (var item2 in Model)
                                        {
                                            @if ((item2.Niveau == 3) && (item2.Pere == item1.Id))
                                            {
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id=@item2.Libelle><label for=@item2.Libelle>@item2.Libelle</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul> 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </li>
                                   </ul>
                                }
                            }
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    }
         </div>
    </div>
}
```

What is the most optimized way to do this? Can we do recursive in html?
Thank you for your reply

Comment: since I not know what interprets your template but every tech i know allows this, I'd just say: yes

Comment: sorry for the sarcasm, that's not plain or pure html and it might drastically help if we'd know what kind of file we're looking at. it at least looks like a `.cshtml` or `.razor` file

Comment: np, it is true that some information are missing.
I use a razor page (the page is called by an action in a controller). 
I'm wondering how to avoid iterating through my entire list on each iteration as this will affect performance.

Comment: btw, the "Niveau" attribute is useless, i manage to have the same result using only the Father attribute (item parent id).

Comment: than, i think you could use [@helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422895/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-recursive-function) to recursively render and I'd probably presort the data using [Enumerable.ToLookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.Enumerable.ToLookup?view=net-6.0) and selecting the id of the parent as key, that you also have too pass to the `helper`, this will allow you to select the children way more efficiently than iterating the whole list on each level